# Rails 3 application background-image and color pushed to bottom of page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I have build a standard Rails 3 application (using Ruby 1.9.2).

I placed all the links to my css files in the stylesheet_link_tag in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file. When I run the application all the styles in the css files work except that the background-image and color are pushed below the content from the view content from the model views in the app/views folders instead of laying on top of the image and color. In my css file I have the background-image attached to the html tag (code below).

```
html {
      background-color:#ccdbce;
      background-image: url('images/bg-body.png');
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-position: top;
      color:#444;
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Attach image showing the current output and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following small modification to the background-position:

```
html {
      background-color:#ccdbce;
      background-image: url('images/bg-body.png');
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-position: left top;
      color:#444;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer. I made the change in my code but everything still remains at the bottom of the page.